# JOIN or analytic function to match different sensors on nearby timestamps within a large dataset?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a large dataset consisting of four sensors in a single stream, but for simplicity's sake let's reduce that to two sensors that transmit at approximate (but not exact) same times like this:

```
+---------+-------------+-------+
| Sensor  |    Time     | Value |
+---------+-------------+-------+
| SensorA | 10:00:01.14 |    10 |
| SensorB | 10:00:01.06 |     8 |
| SensorA | 10:00:02.15 |    11 |
| SensorB | 10:00:02.07 |     9 |
| SensorA | 10:00:03.14 |    13 |
| SensorA | 10:00:04.09 |    12 |
| SensorB | 10:00:04.13 |     6 |
+---------+-------------+-------+
```

I am trying to find the **difference between SensorA and SensorB when their readings are within a half-second of each other**. Like this:

```
+-------------+-------+
| Trunc_Time  |  Diff |
+-------------+-------+
| 10:00:01    |     2 |
| 10:00:02    |     2 |
| 10:00:04    |     6 |
+-------------+-------+
```

I know I could write queries to put each sensor in its own table (say SensorA_table and SensorB_table), and then join those tables like this:

```
  SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(a.Time, SECOND) as truncated_sec,
    a.Value - b.Value as sensor_diff
  FROM SensorA_table AS a JOIN SensorB_Table AS b
  ON b.Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(a.Time, INTERVAL 500 MILLISECOND) AND TIMESTAMP_ADD(a.Time, INTERVAL 500 MILLISECOND)
```

But that seems very expensive to make every row of the SensorA_table compare against every row of the SensorB_table, given that the sensor tables are each about 10 TB. Or does partitioning automatically take care of this and only look at one block of SensorB's table per row of SensorA's table?

Either way, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than a full JOIN. Since the matching values are all coming from within a few rows of each other in the original table, it seems like an analytic function might be able to look at a smaller amount of data at a time, but because we can't guarantee alternating rows of A & B, there's no clear LAG or LEAD offset that would always return the correct row.

Is it a matter of writing an analytic functions to return a few LAG and LEAD rows for each row, then evaluate each of those rows with a CASE statement to see if it is the correct row, then calculating the value? Or is there a way of doing a join against an analytic function's window?

Thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: What if two consecutive records belong to `SensorA`?

Comment: Please show us your expected results as well.

Comment: If you are using the whole table, this is going to be an expensive query anyway, the self-join doesn't change the cost, only perhaps affecting query execution time.  Is this something you will need to do frequently?  If so, you will probably need to run it once to get a result set up to 'now', and then create a process that only looks at the last day (or N days) and appends it to your results.  Regardless, this table is a prime example of when to use partitioning and clustering.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `lag()`.  Something like this:

```
select st.time, st.value - st.prev_value
from (select st.*,
             lag(sensor) over (order by time, sensor) as prev_sensor,
             lag(time) over (order by time, sensor) as prev_time,
             lag(value) over (order by time, sensor) as prev_value
      from sensor_table st
     ) st
where ( st.sensor = 'A' <> prev_sensor = 'B' ) and
      prev_time > timestamp_add(time, interval 1 second)
```

Comment: The problem with using LAG and LEAD is that we don't know whether the other sensor's values will be 1 or 2 lines above or may never be there, so we can't count on a single offset to work consistently.

Comment: @A.Larimer . . . You can add a filter for just sensors A and B in the subquery.  This works, because you only need to do this detection when the sensor changes.